# Splitting field of irreducible polynomial over finite field

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field with $q=p^r$ elements where $p$ - prime. Let $f(x)\in \mathbb{F}_q[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$. Am I right that $\mathbb{F}_q[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$ is the splitting field for $f(x)$?

**P.S.** I've proved it but would like to know is my observation correct?

Comment: "I've proved it but would like to know is my observation correct?" Then please, show us your proof, and we shall take a look at it.

Comment: Also, we have covered this very question on our site many times already. Did you search? Anyway, the extension $K/\Bbb{F}_q$, $K=\Bbb{F}_q[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$ is Galois, hence normal, which implies that all the irreducible polynomials from $\Bbb{F}_q[x]$ with a zero in $K$ split into linear factors over $K$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, dear Jyrki could you take a look at this question, please?

Answer (score 0):

$K=\mathbb{F}_q[x]/(f)$ is a $\mathbb{F}_q$ vector space of dimension $n$, it has $q^n$ elements. $K-\{0\}$ is a cyclic group of order $q^n-1$ so $K$ is the splitting field of $X^{p^n}-X$ since $f$ divides $X^{p^n}-X$ all the roots of $f$ are in $K$.